# Enqueue specific script on account creation (and never again)

Tags: wp-enqueue-script

I'd like to submit a Google Analytics event when a user creates an account.

Right now I'm checking for the presence of a 'first_login' user meta value on every page load.  If it doesn't exist, the event JS script is enqueued and then the 'first_login' meta key is set.

For example:

```
// Enqueue a script that triggers a "new user" Google Analytics event
function new_user_tracking_script(){

    // Check if first visit time is unset
    if ( is_user_logged_in() && !get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), 'first_login', true) ){

        // Google Analytics
        wp_enqueue_script( 'new_user_tracking' );

        // Set first visit time
        update_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'first_login', time() );

    }

}
```

This works but feels gross.  Is there a better way to handle something like this?

Answer (score 1):

This is how you would use the [user_register](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register) hook to load your script:

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'new_user_tracking_script' )

function new_user_tracking_script(){
    // Google Analytics
    wp_enqueue_script( 'new_user_tracking' );
}
```